# Color change of all cards instead of only one

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

[image]

I want to change the color of my vehicle card by clicking on my maker. The problem is if I click on whatever marker it changes all the colors of all vehicle cards. My Js file GoogleMap is the child component. With jquery I know how to do it by the id but with react it's different.

From my child component ( GoogleMap)

```
// Display Marker
  displayMarkers = () => {
    if(this.props.vehicles.length > 0){
      return this.props.vehicles.map((vehicle) => {
        return <Marker 
        google={this.props.google}
        key={vehicle._id} 
        id={vehicle.id} 
        animation= {this.props.google.maps.Animation.DROP}
        position={{
          lat: vehicle.lat,
          lng: vehicle.lng
        }}
        icon={{
          url: image,
          anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(16,16),
          scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(32, 32)
        }}
        onClick={()=> this.props.action(vehicle._id)}
        />
        })
    } else{
      return (<div>Nothing Found...</div>)
    }
  }
```

My Parent component

```
// This method will be sent to the child component
    handler=(vehicleId)=>{
        console.log(vehicleId) // Give me the id when i click on it 
        if(vehicleId){
            this.setState({
                classCard: `card horizontal red`
            });
        } 
    }

    // Render Vehicles
    renderListVehicle=()=>{
        if(this.props.vehicles.length > 0){
            return this.props.vehicles.map(vehicle =>{
                return(
                    <div ref={vehicle._id} key={vehicle._id} className={this.state.classCard}>
                    <div className="card-image">
                    <img src={vehicle.image} alt={vehicle._id}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-stacked">
                    <div className="card-content">
                        <p>{vehicle.name}</p>
                        <p>{vehicle.city}</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                )
            })
        } else{
            return <div>Nothing found!</div>
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>Search for {this.props.match.params.city}</h3>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col m6 s12'>
                        {this.renderListVehicle()}
                    </div>
                    <div className='col m6 s12'>
                        <GoogleMap action={this.handler}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Actually if I click on the marker, it changes all cards colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an array of class for each vehicle because using a single variable to store class would impact all cards.

Handler function would look like :

```
// ...
if(vehicleId){
    this.setState({
       classCard: { ...this.state.classCard, [vehicleId]: `card horizontal red`
    });
}
// ...
```

And vehicle item display would contain:

```
<div ref={vehicle._id} key={vehicle._id} className={this.state.classCard[vehicleId]}>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mika Andrianarijaona. It's working. question why did you put 3 dotes  ... this.state.classCard what does it mean?

Comment: They are used to "extract" the content of this.state.classCard. It is called destructuring, you should check it, it's quite helpful.